# Google App Engine, Illegal string in dataset id when uploading to local datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Using the bulk loader, I've downloaded the live datastore, and am now trying to upload it to the development server. When running the upload_data command to upload the datastore to the dev server I get the following error,

`BadRequestError: Illegal string "dev~s~app_id" in dataset id`.

The command I'm using the upload the data is

`appcfg.py upload_data --url=://localhost:8080/_ah/remote_api --filename=datastore_2-11-14`

The command I used the downlaod the data is

`appcfg.py download_data --url=://app_id.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api --filename=datastore_2-11-14`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to discover the problem on my own.

The issue was with adding s~ before the app_id in the app.yaml file.

Despite the Google App Engine documentation stating that s~ should be before the app_id for applications using the High Replication Datastore, this apparently causes an error when uploading the the development server.